# Registering Facebook achievements - Object at achievement URL is not of type game.achievement

Tags: facebook

I keep getting this error, even though from both raw html (there are actual values in my case, not '...'s):

```
<meta content='game.achievement' property='og:type'> 
<meta content='...' property='og:title'> 
<meta content='...' property='og:url'> 
<meta content='...' property='og:description'> 
<meta content='...' property='og:image'> 
<meta content='1' property='game:points'> 
<meta content='...' property='fb:app_id'>
```

and http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ it looks like everything's fine. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific? The link you provided is a generic uri.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `description` meta tag in my head (in addition to the `og:description` meta tag.)

Removing the former solved this problem for me. For some reason it was breaking the achievement scrape on the URL. In general, I would try removing *everything* besides your `og:` tags from the head.

Additionally, repeatedly linting and re-posting the urls seemed to work eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you url is, but I saw this problem when the og:url property pointed to my app (ie, https://apps.facebook.com/appname/somefile). I had to change it to the exact URL on my server to get it registered, then after I registered it, I was able to change it back to the app url so that when users click it they are taken to my app.

Answer (score 0):

When creating achievements you have to use the direct link of the page on your site. This will hold the meta tags. In your code where you are resgistering and then posting an achievement you have to use the canvas type url.